# Ios Debugging with GDB and No Symbols - Examine Objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, gdb

I am debugging an ios application that i don't have the source code for and it's a stripped binary, so there are no symbols that i can use. I therefore use addresses to set bps with the help of IDA and class-dump. I have come into situations where i cannot really understand the return value or parameter of a specific method. I know that the parameters are supposed to be on $r2 registers and on and that the return value of methods is on $r0.

Let's take the subDataWithRange method which returns an NSData* pointer. Of course, I cannot do "po pointer_addr" because i have no symbols and thus gdb fails. So, I am trying to examine the contents on my own. Though i am pretty sure on the bytes i should be getting back, i do retrieve a pointer, but when i do something like "x/20x $r0" to examine its contents, i do not see meaningful bytes.

Therefore I would like to ask about the structure of an NSData* object and other ios objects like NSString as they would appear in raw bytes in memory. What is the structure like ? Is there a pointer somewhere inside the structure that i have failed to locate, that actually points to the returned bytes ?

Answer (score 0):

You may be lucky and get a reasonable glimpse at the implementation from [Apple's Open Source CFLite releases](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-744.18/), where `CFData` is defined as:

```
struct __CFData {
    CFRuntimeBase _base;
    CFIndex _length;    /* number of bytes */
    CFIndex _capacity;  /* maximum number of bytes */
    CFAllocatorRef _bytesDeallocator;   /* used only for immutable; if NULL, no deallocation */
    uint8_t *_bytes;    /* compaction: direct access to _bytes is only valid when data is not inline */
};
```

Which will give you some clues of how the object is laid-out in memory, however the source code to much of the frameworks is private and you will have to resort to trial-and-error in order to get *any* understanding of how they are implemented.

To add to the confusion, many `NS` objects are toll-free bridged to their `CF` equivalents, and `NSData`/`CFData` is one of those objects.  I am unsure of the impact this will have.

I do not envy your task.